# Angular2-Seed & ngx-pipes

Tags: angular, angular2-seed

Can anyone help me to get the ngx-pipes (https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes) included in the angular2-seed? I tried it like this in the project-config.ts:

additionalPackages.push({
      name: 'ngx-pipes',
      path: 'node_modules/ngx-pipes/src/app/index.js'
    });

```
additionalPackages.push({
  name: 'ngx-pipes/src/app/pipes/*.js',
  path: 'node_modules/ngx-pipes/src/app/pipes/*/index.js'
});
```

but then only the main file index.js is loaded correctly, but not the subfiles.